# How to embed python 3.8+ in a C++ application while using a virtual environment?

Tags: c++, python-3.x, windows, python-venv, python-embedding

*This is a self-answered question. I've found that there aren't any good examples of this specific situation, and the seemingly related questions don't address this use case.*

My C++ application previously embedded Python 2.7 using a virtual environment. This was done using `Py_SetPythonHome(venv_path)` followed by `Py_Initialize()`. Currently, I am migrating the app to Python 3. Python 3.8 introduces the new [Python Initialization Configuration](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init_config.html) API, which is now the preferred method of initialization. Additionally, it introduces the concept of an "isolated" initialization, which I would like to use here. However, when I try to use this API in a similar way to the Python 2.7 initialization by setting `config.home`, I get an initialization error that suggest that the base Python libraries could not be found.

My virtual environment is initialized as follows:

```
py -3.10 -m venv C:\path\to\venv
```

When I execute the following code:

```cpp
PyConfig config;
PyConfig_InitIsolatedConfig(&config);

auto venv_path = L"C:\\path\\to\\venv";
PyConfig_SetString(&config, &config.home, venv_path);

status = Py_InitializeFromConfig(&config);
PyConfig_Clear(&config);

if (PyStatus_Exception(status)) {
    std::cout << "status.func: " << (status.func ? status.func : "N/A") << '\n';
    std::cout << "status.err_msg: " << (status.err_msg ? status.err_msg : "N/A") << '\n';
}
```

I get the following output and error message:

```
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = 'C:\path\to\venv'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python'
  isolated = 1
  environment = 0
  user site = 0
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\demo\\build\\PythonDemo.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'C:\\path\\to\\venv'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'C:\\path\\to\\venv'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\demo\\build\\PythonDemo.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'C:\\path\\to\\venv'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'C:\\path\\to\\venv'
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Python310\\python310.zip',
    'C:\\path\\to\\venv\\DLLs',
    'C:\\path\\to\\venv\\lib',
    'C:\\demo\\build',
  ]
status.func: init_fs_encoding
status.err_msg: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
```

The initialization configuration documentation specifically mentions "The following configuration files are used by the path configuration: `pyvenv.cfg` [...]", suggesting that virtual environments should be properly handled during initialization. However, it doesn't seem like the initialization is finding that file based on only setting `config.home`, and assumes that `C:\path\to\venv` is a complete Python installation rather than a virtual environment.

I've found that manually setting `base_prefix` and `base_exec_prefix` to `C:\Python310` (partially) resolves the issue. However, I do not want to hardcode the path to Python in my application, as the app's users may have installed Python somewhere else. Besides, the `home` path provided in `pyvenv.cfg` should be automatically used for these.

How do I get `Py_InitializeFromConfig` to properly handle my virtual environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has a built-in way of handling virtual environments using the [`site` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html).

> **This module is automatically imported during initialization.** [...]
>
> If a file named “pyvenv.cfg” exists one directory above sys.executable, sys.prefix and sys.exec_prefix are set to that directory and it is also checked for site-packages (sys.base_prefix and sys.base_exec_prefix will always be the “real” prefixes of the Python installation).

In short, **instead of setting `config.home` to `<venv>`, set `config.executable` to `<venv>\Scripts\python.exe`.** Setting `config.home` manually interferes with Python's automatic virtual environment detection.

```cpp
PyConfig config;
PyConfig_InitIsolatedConfig(&config);

auto venv_executable = L"C:\\path\\to\\venv\\Scripts\\python.exe";
PyConfig_SetString(&config, &config.executable, venv_executable);

status = Py_InitializeFromConfig(&config);
PyConfig_Clear(&config);

if (PyStatus_Exception(status)) {
    Py_ExitStatusException(status);
}

PyRun_SimpleString("import sys; print(f'{sys.executable=}\\n{sys.prefix=}\\n{sys.exec_prefix=}\\n{sys.base_prefix=}\\n{sys.base_exec_prefix=}\\n{sys.path=}')");
```

The above will produce the following output, showing that the virtual environment has been successfully identified and that the proper values are used for the various `sys` attributes.

```
sys.executable='C:\\path\\to\\venv\\Scripts\\python.exe'
sys.prefix='C:\\path\\to\\venv'
sys.exec_prefix='C:\\path\\to\\venv'
sys.base_prefix='C:\\Python310'
sys.base_exec_prefix='C:\\Python310'
sys.path=['C:\\Python310\\python310.zip', 'C:\\Python310\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\Python310', 'C:\\path\\to\\venv', 'C:\\path\\to\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are encountering issues with `Py_InitializeFromConfig` when trying to initialize Python 3 within a virtual environment. To properly handle your virtual environment during initialization, you might need to consider a different approach.

Instead of setting `config.home` directly, you can leverage the `PyConfig_SetBytes` function to set the home directory in bytes, which is expected for virtual environments. Additionally, you can use `PyConfig_SetString` to set the home directory as a string for compatibility.

Here's an adjusted version of your code:

```cpp
    PyConfig config;
    PyConfig_InitIsolatedConfig(&config);
    
    const wchar_t* venv_path = L"C:\\path\\to\\venv";
    PyConfig_SetBytes(&config, &config.home, reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(venv_path), wcslen(venv_path) * sizeof(wchar_t));
    
    status = Py_InitializeFromConfig(&config);
    PyConfig_Clear(&config);
    
    if (PyStatus_Exception(status)) {
        std::cout << "status.func: " << (status.func ? status.func : "N/A") << '\n';
        std::cout << "status.err_msg: " << (status.err_msg ? status.err_msg : "N/A") << '\n';
    }
```

By using `PyConfig_SetBytes` and passing the bytes representation of the home directory, you ensure proper handling of the virtual environment during initialization. This should help resolve the issue you're facing with `Py_InitializeFromConfig` in the context of Python 3 and virtual environments.

Comment: This answer only has to do with _how_ `config.home` is set and doesn't resolve the underlying issue.